# Tunnel traffic between PPTP and OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pptp

My office (`office_network`) uses PPTP VPN for remote employees. And it was OK before macOS Catalina release. Macos doesn't support PPTP anymore at all.

So, to get access to `office_network` network I decided to setup "vpn tunel" on my Ubuntu server (`ubuntu`).

- I've installed PPTP client on `ubuntu` and connected to `office_network`
- I've installed openVPN server on `ubuntu` and also client on my macbook (`macbook`) and successfully connected (`ubuntu` <-> `macbook`). I can go to the internet via `ubuntu`

But I still can't get access to `office_network` from `macbook`.

ifconfig from `ubuntu`:

```
root@server:/etc/openvpn# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet X.Y.244.154  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast X.Y.244.255
        inet6 ....  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 ....  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ....  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8115596  bytes 1387222400 (1.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10933097  bytes 2330386079 (2.3 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 132556  bytes 90634105 (90.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 132556  bytes 90634105 (90.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 10.10.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.10.10.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 102  bytes 115715 (115.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 94  bytes 9170 (9.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 ....  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 29916  bytes 6166802 (6.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 126423  bytes 156305569 (156.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 4791 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ppp0` - it's pptp interface. `tun0` - openvpn server

Actually I need access only to one subnet from `office_network`, so I've added a route

```
ip route add 10.80.16.0/24 dev ppp0
```

As result I can get access to 10.80.16.X from `ubuntu`, but not from `macbook`.

Also `traceroute` from `macbook`:

Success to google:

```
➜  ~ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.169.46), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  48.696 ms  45.363 ms  48.516 ms
 2  router2-lon.hosting-server.com (X.Y.33.230)  46.275 ms  49.215 ms  49.843 ms
 3  109.74.207.20 (109.74.207.20)  46.062 ms  48.806 ms  45.548 ms
 ...
```

Failed to `office_network`

```
➜  ~ traceroute 10.80.16.14
traceroute to 10.80.16.14 (10.80.16.14), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  47.852 ms  48.493 ms  64.061 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 ......
```

Finally I've tried to add NAT rule like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.80.16.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it also doesn't help.

What did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

Add this route to NAT table:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```